# How do I move the logo in the left position before sitetile in WordPress?

Tags: php, css, wordpress

I would like to know what do i need to add in css to make the logo move in the left position before site-title in WordPress?

```
// Display Site Title
add_action( 'smartline_site_title', 'smartline_display_site_title' );

function smartline_display_site_title() { ?>

    <img src="<?php bloginfo('template_directory');?>/images/AA.gif">
    <a href="<?php echo esc_url(home_url('/')); ?>" title="<?php echo esc_attr( get_bloginfo( 'name', 'display' ) ); ?>" rel="home">
        <h1 class="site-title"><?php bloginfo('name'); ?></h1>
    </a>
    <?php
}
```

Comment: Do you want to have the logo centered to the site title ?

Comment: I would like it to left then site title appear after logo

Comment: something like this : http://s23.postimg.org/hl80c92or/temporary1.png

Comment: I want the logo to appear first in left hand side of the header then  site title to show after it. is it possible for me to do.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This should do it :

Add `#logo img{float:left;}` code to your CSS and then check.

**EDITED**

```
#logo img{float:left;margin-top:-3%;}

#logo .site-title{margin-top:2%;}
```

Comment: Yes it has worked but however would i need to make image size smaller so it appear on same line as site title.

Comment: Add my edited answer and you will not need to resize the image to achieve it.

Comment: Thank you it has worked :) Would i need to add responsive code into css for mobile view

Comment: Glad it helped you! You can accept it as answer.
It depends but I don't think it will make an issue as we have used `%`

Comment: Thank you sir :). I will have a go and play around with it.

Answer (score 0):

```
    <!--logo-floater-->
    <div id="logo-floater"> 
        <?php if ($logo): ?>
        <a href="<?php print check_url($front_page); ?>" title="<?php print t('Home'); ?>">
        <img src="<?php print $logo; ?>" alt="<?php print t('Home'); ?>" />
        </a>
        <?php endif; ?>

        <?php if ($site_name || $site_slogan): ?>
        <div class="clearfix">
            <?php if ($site_name): ?>
            <span id="site-name"><a href="<?php print check_url($front_page); ?>" title="<?php print t('Home'); ?>"><?php print $site_name; ?></a></span>
            <?php endif; ?>

            <?php if ($site_slogan): ?>
            <span id="slogan"><?php print $site_slogan; ?></span>
            <?php endif; ?>
        </div>
        <?php endif; ?>
    </div> <!--EOF:logo-floater-->
```

This displays the logo first, to switch them try,

```
     <!--logo-floater-->
    <div id="logo-floater"> 

        <?php if ($site_name || $site_slogan): ?>
        <div class="clearfix">
            <?php if ($site_name): ?>
            <span id="site-name"><a href="<?php print check_url($front_page); ?>" title="<?php print t('Home'); ?>"><?php print $site_name; ?></a></span>
            <?php endif; ?>

            <?php if ($site_slogan): ?>
            <span id="slogan"><?php print $site_slogan; ?></span>
            <?php endif; ?>
        </div>
        <?php endif; ?>

        <?php if ($logo): ?>
        <a href="<?php print check_url($front_page); ?>" title="<?php print t('Home'); ?>">
        <img src="<?php print $logo; ?>" alt="<?php print t('Home'); ?>" />
        </a>
        <?php endif; ?>
    </div> <!--EOF:logo-floater-->
```